# How can i keep password for a folder?

Tags: password, directory

I want to keep password for my important folder where my all the documents are kept so how can i keep password for it?

[image: cannot enter password]

Comment: Do you mean, how you can password protect a folder where all your documents are kept? Do you want to create a private encrypted folder? If so see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory

Comment: See also [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/27770/178596) and [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/59203/how-can-i-protect-my-data-when-lending-my-computer-to-someone/59204#59204).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stop people accessing a file or folder, encrypting the file with a password is a great way to do it. First either open Archive Manager and click <kbd>New</kbd>, or right-click on the folder you want to protect and press 'Compress'.

Then chose a compression format you can encrypt (e.g. `.7z`, `.arj`, etc) <sub>*(under Other Options)*</sub>. Using `7z`ip compression is good, as then you can encrypt the file list to. Then type the password you want to use.

[image]

Then you can add files:

[image]

Then you have an encrypted archive with your files secure inside - though it can still be deleted... [image]

You can also hide the compressed file by adding a `.` to the beginning of the file name, so it only shows when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

Comment: There  is password option but i cannot enter password in it

Comment: @wilf how did you create that emoticon its so sreative and very attractive

Comment: @agharehanabbas - I did create/modify some emoticons a while ago using [the GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) - you can do neat animated ones using GIF or a similar format. If I didn't create this one, I probably found it on Google Images :D. To create one, you can using [paths](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Drawing_Shapes/), the circle select tool, gradients etc - stroke [selection](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-selection-stroke.html)/[path](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-path-stroke.html) can be used to draw the outlines.

Comment: thanks i will experiment this thing i am very curious about it :D

Answer (score 1):

By default, your first line of defense is linux permissions and your regular password.

```
sudo chown your_user:your_user /home/your_user/some_directory
chmod 700 /home/your_user/some_directory
chomd 600 /home/your_user/some_directory/*
```

use 700 for sub directories as well (600 for files).

That will not protect against sharing your account , or someone with physical or root access.

To protect from root / physical access you have to use encryption. You have several options for encryption from a private, encrypted home directory to gpg to cryptkeeper . cyptkeeper is a graphical tool and will encrypt the directory.

Note: as long as the directory is decrypted is is accessible to root and other users with the appropriate permissions.